# ¿Como agregar botones por cada registro, con angular-datatablejs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla que la lleno de esta manera

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $("#example-1").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                "url": "http://162.222.100.163/proyecto/public/ws/usuarios",
                "dataSrc": "records"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "nombre1" },
                    { "data": "nombre2" },
                    { "data": "apellido1" },
                    { "data": "apellido2" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>               
    <table id="example-1" class="table table-striped table-bordered " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Tipo Usuario</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>                                         
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Tipo Usuario</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

la table me funciona completamente, busqueda y paginacion. Pero por cada registro debo agregarle un boton y resulta que en el boton, debo agregarle la directiva ng-click para que abra un modal. Es esto posible. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

necesitas agregar la propiedad `columnDefs`

```
$("#example-1").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        //...
    },
    "columns": [
        //...
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: -1, //posición de la columna donde estara el boton
        data: null,
        className: "d-flex",
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        defaultContent: "<a class='btn delete-data'>"
    }],
    drawCallback: (settings) => {
        $('.delete-data').click(()=>{
            //accion
        });
    }
});
```

Puedes ver la domentacion de esta [aqui](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente inserta el boton en una celda de la tabla por cada fila, este boton asiganale en ng-click una funcion que este en tu controlador, si tiene que hacer algo respecto a loa datos de esa columna pasale el id del item. Nose si me dejo entender.